# What happens to a DWG file once it has been translated into an SVF file?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

When I use the Model Derivative API to translate a DWG file into an SVF file, what happens to the DWG file?

Does it get stored in my bucket along with the SVF? Does it get stored somewhere else? Does it get thrown away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what policy you set for your bucket when you create it. You can choose a retention policy of either transient, temporary, or persistent, meaning that uploaded files (ie your DWGs before conversion, not the SVFs) will be kept for either 24 hours, 30 days, or permanently.

Read [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/) for more information.

Comment: Correct, the original (seed) file remains in the bucket for a time period based on the bucket's data retention policy, or until you remove it.